# Can a $TEM_{00}$ beam incident on a confocal cavity along its optical axis excite modes other than $TEM_{00}$ in the cavity?

Tags: optics, resonance

Can a $TEM_{00}$ beam incident on a confocal cavity along its optical axis excite modes other than $TEM_{00}$ in the cavity?

If not, is the FSR of the confocal cavity $\frac{c}{2L}$ in this case, instead of the oft-quoted $FSR=\frac{c}{4L}$?